# hex dependencies not found for elixir project - poison, absinthe

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-poison, absinthe, hex-pm

I am getting `unchecked dependency for environment` error for `ecto.create` and `ecto.migrate`. I have below `mix.exs` file dependency entry

```
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.3"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.3"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.1", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:absinthe, "~> 1.4"},
     {:absinthe_plug, "~> 1.4"},
     {:absinthe_ecto, "~> 0.1.3"},
     {:proper_case, "~> 1.0.0"},
     {:rbmq, "~> 0.4"},
     {:lager_logger, "~> 1.0"},
     {:quantum, "~> 2.2"},
     {:timex, "~> 3.0"},
     #{:amqp_client, "~> 3.6.7-pre.1", override: true},
     #{:rabbit_common, "~> 3.6.7-pre.1", override: true},
     {:httpoison, "~> 0.11.0"},
     {:confex, "~> 1.4"},
     {:cors_plug, "~> 1.5"},
     {:logger_file_backend, "~> 0.0.9"},
     {:distillery, "~> 1.1"},
     {:keycloak, "~> 0.2.0"},
     {:plug, "~> 1.4", override: true},
     {:poison, "~> 3.1", override: true}]
  end
```

when I run the command `mix ecto.create && mix ecto.migrate` I get below error.

```
  Unchecked dependencies for environment dev:
* absinthe (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 1.4", got "1.2.5"
* poison (Hex package)
  the dependency does not match the requirement "~> 3.1", got "2.2.0"
** (Mix) Can't continue due to errors on dependencies
```

I am a greenhorn in hex,elixir and mix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be due to `cache issue`

Run below command

`mix deps.clean --all`

This cleans the local cache of hex repository

and then

`mix deps.get`

which downloads the latest dependencies

Comment: Thank you. This has solved the issue but I am getting more error
`===> Compiling src/ranch_proxy_ssl.erl failed
src/ranch_proxy_ssl.erl:90: ssl:ssl_accept/3: deprecated; use ssl:handshake/3 instead

** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :ranch_proxy_protocol, "/Users/a5634160/.mix/rebar3 bare compile --paths "/Users/a5634160/Documents/parc_web/pfom/_build/dev/lib/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile ranch_proxy_protocol", update it with "mix deps.update ranch_proxy_protocol" or clean it with "mix deps.clean ranch_proxy_protocol"`

Comment: put this as a separate question and provide link here.

Comment: Here is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475951/elixirhex-getting-hex-error-for-ranch-proxy-protocol-sslssl-accept-3-depreca

Answer (score 1):

Run `mix deps.get` to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you. But this didn't help. Same error. Here is the output of `mix deps.get` 
`Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  absinthe 1.4.12
  absinthe_ecto 0.1.3
  absinthe_plug 1.4.4
  amqp 1.0.3
  amqp_client 3.7.5
  base64url 0.0.1
  certifi 1.2.1
  combine 0.10.0
`